# Apps made for iphone 4 and iphone 5 are supported in iphone 6 and iphone 6 plus or not

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, iphone-6

My question is to get knowlegde regarding whether the app created for iphone 4 and 5 in ios 7 are supported in iphone 6 and iphone 6 plus or not??

If not supported then how  i can provide support to the apps so that it can run in iphone 6 and iphone 6 plus

Comment: Well all app's would be provided in both iphone 6 and 6 plus but for that you need to make changes in code for iOS 8 compatibility and also take size of screen into consideration. For adjusting size go for autlayout and start fixing/making those changes. Rest code logic and method is available or deprecated will depend so start off with your work.

Comment: @walle84 If auto resizing is provided then there wont require to take screen size in to consideration?? and code written in obj c will run in iphone 6?

Comment: Yes but I'm definitely sure that your UI will have some issue(minor or major no idea) as screen size is increased so the look and feel will.

Comment: I have tried if auto resizing is done then it appears same so i am also confused

Comment: Okay so if u come cross something do let me know and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To provide iOS 8 support, need to  xcode 6. As far as code is concerned, it depends on the xcode 6 requirement. We need to update only those functions those are deprecated in iOS 8. And for the UI, apple introduced 2 new screen size 4.7 and 5.5 inch. We need to use autolayout to manage the UI. Please let me know if any other issue. Thanks.

Comment: if i want to provide support to app created in ios 6 then do i need to change anything if auto resizing is already done so if i am running that app in xcode 6 still ui appears same as it was before so no change is found

Answer (score 1):

If your app is in App Store, you can download and install the app right in your iOS 8 device.
Showing as iOS 7 5s device, but if you use Xcode 6 (include iOS 8) you should rewrite some code to adapt for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus.
That means if you use Xcode 5 to build the ipa, no iOS 8 features will be shown.

Comment: if i am using xcode 6 then what kind of code i need to write?
should i provide condition that if ios 8 then screen size should be as per iphone 6 else iphone 5s?

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are supported but you need to change User interface  according to size of screen for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus because image resolutions .there are so many method which are depreciated in iOS 8 so Be care full when you will update the Application

Comment: I am new in ios so asking you few things if code written in obj c then do i need to change anything in code to provide support? and if auto resizing is given then will it create any problem regarding screen size?

Answer (score 1):

New iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+ will scale exiting apps to fit there screen sizes.
There are more than **1.3 millions apps** available on app store and Apple taken care of those apps.
To get benefits of new iOS devices and `iOS8` features you need to use `xCode6 GM`.
Optimization for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+ will be done using Auto resizing property.
Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone-6) of iPhone6 questions which might help you.